# Material UI DateRange Picker --> DateTimeRange Picker?

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, material-ui

I'm debating purchasing the Material UI-X commercial license because I need access to the DateRange picker component- however, it is crucial that I am also able to select a time range as well, and further need to be able to have a time range within the same day. Is this feature available with the current state of Material UI's date range picker components? It's not obvious in the [documentation](https://next.material-ui.com/components/date-range-picker/). If not, is it coming in the future?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't include time range picking abilities. For that sort of functionality, you'd be better off developing a custom range checker using the [Date Time picker](https://next.material-ui.com/components/date-time-picker/), which supports time picking out-of-the-box and is part of the free version.